# how can I do auto-scaling for cnosdb query engine？

Tags: kubernetes, cnosdb

The Cnosdb query-engine can be serverless, but does the cnosdb query-engine need a unique id in the cluster? if it need unique id, how can i do auto-scaling in kubernetes?